# Updates via RTC scm not being recognised by RTC Eclipse plugin

Tags: rtc

I have a script which :

1. Loads an rtc workspace
2. Checks in a file to the workspace

The checked in file is not being reflected within 'pending changes'. Is there a hook I need to configure (or some other method)
so that any changes made using the scm tool are reflected on the rtc client ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be reflect in the "Pending changes" view only if:

- the local workspace has been loaded (attached to the repo workspace to which your script has checked in a file: it should be the same local workspace)
- you refresh the "Pending changes" view, asking to refresh "Remotes *and* local changes", or to refresh directly the right local workspace)

[image: refresh]

(from "[Using the RTC Eclipse client with other Tools](https://jazz.net/library/article/531/)")

From [that thread](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/49852/pending-changes-view-refresh?redirect=/forum/questions/49852/pending-changes-view-refresh), it seems the "Pending changes" view only refreshed automatically for *remote* changes:

> The Pending Changes view should already refresh itself automatically when your Eclipse client receives RSS feed events reporting there are new incoming change sets.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using the RTC 4.0 Eclipse client on Windows, it might help to enable "Preferences > Team > Jazz Source Control > Local Changes > Automatically detect changes".

See "[Rational Team Concert 4.0 "New and Noteworthy"](https://jazz.net/downloads/rational-team-concert/releases/4.0?p=news#scm_autodetect)"

[image: AutoDetect]